Angular signal set data in input signal change detect
I want to refactor old angular input to signal
I have a component:
  @Input() profileData: AdminAccountProfileResponse = { type: '' };
  profile: ExtendedProfile = { type: '' };


 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['profileData'].currentValue) {
      this.profile = this.profileData;
    }
  }

and in html:
<h4>{{profile.verifiedMobile}}</h4>

I convert it like below but i am not sure it's the best way or not:
  profileData = input<AdminAccountProfileResponse>({ type: '' });
  profile = signal<ExtendedProfile>({ type: '' });


  constructor() {
    toObservable(this.profileData)
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed())
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data) this.profile.set(data);
      });
  }

I also remove ngOnChanges
html:
<h4>{{profile().verifiedMobile}}</h4>


Instead of create a new observable you can just define the profile as compute and use the input signal directly.

As mentioned in the comments by Thomas Renger, the code will look like this.
  profileData = input<AdminAccountProfileResponse>({ type: '' });
  profile = computed(() => {
      const profileData = this.profileData();
      return profileData;
  });


thank you. Why should create a clone? what should I do if I don't want a clone?

@heliyarb skip the commented code

if I skip the commented code, how do I set it? could you please add that version to your answer

and please tell me when I might need a clone.

@heliyarb If you do not want the updates to the properties of profileData Object to be copied to the profile object and vice versa

could you please add the version without a clone to your answer

@heliyarb I removed the clone, since its confusing! thanks!

@heliyarb no problem!

the accepted answer is correct but i got type error and i handled it with this way:
  profileData = input<AdminAccountProfileResponse>({ type: '' });
  profile = computed(() => {
    return this.profileData() as ExtendedProfile
  })

